# Is it possible to dynamic query to stored procedure?

Tags: spring-boot, nativequery, java-stored-procedures

I have a Spring boot application. I need a feature to dynamically query the stored procedure. What I mean by dynamically,

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "getCustomFoo", query = "select * from SP_FOO_CUSTOM where id = 1", resultClass = Foo.class)
```

but id could be any attribute in result set, so it could change based on the users input;

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "getCustomFoo", query = "select * from SP_FOO_CUSTOM where fooid = 1 ", resultClass = Foo.class)
```

Is it possible to do something like this? or this is totally out of standards?